# Write Failed: Bad address

Tags: c

```
/* Write and rewrite */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
 int i = 0;
 int w_rw = 0;
 int fd = -1;
 int bw = -1;
 int nob = 0;
 char* file_name = "myfile";
 char buff[30] = "Dummy File Testing";

 w_rw = 1;       // 1 - write , 2 - rewrite
 nob = 1000000;  // No of bytes to write

 printf("\n File - Create,Open,Write \n");

 for(i = 0; i < w_rw; i++){
        printf("fd:%d line : %d\n",fd,__LINE__);
        if((fd = open(file_name,O_CREAT | O_RDWR))< 0){
                perror("Open failed!");
                return -1;
        }

        printf("fd:%d",fd);
        if((bw = write(fd,buff,nob)) < 0){
                perror("Write failed!");
                return -1;
        }
        printf("\n Bytes written : %d \n",bw);
 }

 return 0;
}
```

I'm getting a write error, Bad address failure when tried to write 1MB bytes of data. why is that so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buff array should be at least nob bytes long for the write call to succeed...

Answer (score 2):

According to man of [write](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) `write() writes up to count bytes from the buffer pointed buf to the file referred to by the file descriptor fd` so you are overrunning the string buffer.

If you want to just fill the file with that string try [fwrite](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fwrite.html), you can specify the string length and the total number of times to write the buffer (nob/strlen(buff) ?).

Comment: die.net is outdated, don't use it.

Comment: @Jori Ok, since I'm not involved with POSIX on a daily basis I was not aware of this, so which man site should I link to?

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis, by adding "opengroup" to your search term, you usually stumble upon the normative pages for all POSIX functions.

Answer (score 2):

```
 ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t nbytes);
```

`write()` system call will read `nbytes` bytes from `buf` and write to file referred by the file descriptor `fd`.

In your program `buf` is small compare to `nbytes` so `write()` trying to access invalid address location, so its giving Bad Address error.

Your `buf` is **buff[30]** change to **buf[1000000]** you can solve your problem.

*Bad Address error means that the address location that you have given is invalid*.

[Wikipedia giving good explanation with example program about write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_%28system_call%29).