# Can't print an int to a file

Tags: c, file, pipe

I'm trying to print an `int array` on a file but it is giving me an error.

```
write_error:Bad address.
```

My `int array` is something like :

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

And I want to print it on a `file` as follows :

```
1 2 3
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

This is the code I'm using :

```
void printToFile(int listBoard[]) {
  int file_write;
  char buffer[100];
  char buffer2[10];
  if ((file_write = open("./board.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0700)) < 0) {
    err_sys("error output file");
  }
  if (write(file_write, snprintf(buffer2, 10, "%d",listBoard[2]), 18) != 18){
    err_sys("write_error");
  }
  if (close(file_write) != 0){
    err_sys("error close write");
  }
}
```

I also tried `(char)` but it converts the `int` to the `ascii char`.

Could you tell me what I'm missing?

### Edit

My file output is :

```
3@\00\00펈㰙\00ጠ
```

Code edited :

```
void printToFile(int listBoard[]){

  int file_write;
  char buffer[100];
  int value;
  int cont = 0;
  char buffer2[10];
  if ((file_write = open("./board.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0700)) < 0) {
      err_sys("error output file");
  }
  int len = snprintf(buffer2, 10, "%d", listBoard[2]);
  if (write(file_write, buffer2, len) != len) {
      err_sys("write_error");
  }
  if (close(file_write) != 0) {
      err_sys("error close write");
  }

}
```

Output file :

```
3
```

### Last edit

This is how I did now to print it as the output that I want

```
if ((file_write = open("./board.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0700)) < 0) {
    err_sys("error output file");
}
for (int index = 0; index < SIZE_BOARD; index++) {
    if (cont == 3) {
        int len = snprintf(buffer2, 1, "%d \n", ' ');
        if(write(file_write, buffer2, len) != len) {
            err_sys("write_error");
            cont=0;
        }
    }
    int len = snprintf(buffer2, 10, "%d ", listBoard[index]);
    if (write(file_write, buffer2, len) != len) {
        err_sys("write_error");
        cont++;
    }
}

if(close(file_write) != 0) {
    err_sys("error close write");
}
```

But it is not doing the `\n` correctly. What I'm missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write Failed: Bad address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303529/write-failed-bad-address)

Comment: If you have a buffer of 10 characters, what do you think happens when you attempt to `write` 18 characters from that buffer?

Comment: I tried to convert it to a char that's why I put a buffer of 10

Comment: But why are you trying to write ***18*** characters from a buffer of 10 characters?

Comment: You must call `snprintf` before `write` and then `write(file_write,buffer2, strlen(buffer2)+1)`

Comment: And how I declare char buffer2?

Comment: As you did with space enough to fit `snprintf` output. +1 added in my comment should be avoided if you do not want to put only chars into destination without null terminator.

Comment: The second printf in your edited code is useless. Get rid of it. BTW you should breath and buy a good [tag:c] book a start study something. You cannot learn how to program in that way. You must understand what a function does and what is used for.

Comment: @LPs I misstyped it sorry

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Your last edit tells `snprintf` to only "print" *one* character. The second argument should be e.g. `sizeof(buffer2)`

Comment: Reminder to approve an answer @StuartDTO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of write is as follows:

```
ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

The definition of snprintf is as follows:

```
int snprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...);
```

Now you're feeding snprintf to where write is expecting `void *buf`. i.e. the address to where the data is.

So you'll have to do

```
snprintf(buffer2, 10, "%d", listBoard[2]);
```

then

```
write(file_write, buffer2, 18);
```

**EDIT:**

That will fix the syntax error. Now semantically you can see that you're writing 10 bytes to buffer2 but you're writing 18 to the file. This will fill the file with junk. So i suggest.

```
int len = snprintf(buffer2, 10, "%d", listBoard[2]);
write(file_write, buffer2, len);
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
int len = snprintf(buffer2, 1, "%d \n", ' ');
```

First off your format specifier has *3* bytes while you're only writing *1* byte to the buffer2. Second, why is your argument `' '` when you're supposed to give the `listBoard[n]`?

Comment: I think we did the same edit, so yours is not shows :/

Comment: on my question I mean

Comment: Is that after what I suggested? @Stuart2041

Comment: You make the same mistake as the OP in the call to `write`. The buffer is only 10 character (including terminator), but the string may be shorter.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I wasn't addressing that, I was just talking about the syntax used! :) I'll edit my answer

Comment: Nice, it now shows a 3 but what about the space and \n?

Comment: @Stuart2041 you'll have to add that in to the format. Like `"%d \n"`.

Comment: And to write a space? because I don't need listBoard do I need a buffer aswell?

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: @Stuart2041 Approve the answer, Changing your question multiple times is not the way to go. Different question requires a different thread :)

Comment: It's not a different question since start is the same question... :S

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts

Comment: I put this `int len = snprintf(buffer2, 1, "%d \n", ' ');` because I want an space as you can see as my expected output on my question....

Answer (score 2):

Use `dprintf()` to write formatted strings to files:

```
dprintf(file_write, "%d", listBoard[2]);
```

`dprintf` will handle all the write stuff for you, so this is the only call you need with open and close.

`dprintf` is the `fprintf` for file descriptors. More informations here: https://linux.die.net/man/3/dprintf

Comment: But the thing is I have to write it to the document with `space` and `\n`

Comment: The add a space and a \n to your format `"%d \n"` or so.

Comment: Can you provide a little example?

Comment: The `fprintf` function uses C standard `FILE*` streams, not POSIX file descriptors.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for noticing, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 0):

The [`snprintf` (and family) functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) returns an *integer*.

You use this integer in the `write` call as a pointer to a buffer. That will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Call `snprintf` separately, and then pass `buffer2` as the second argument. And use `strlen` to get the *actual* length of the string in `buffer2`, not hard-code the magic number `18` which will lead to reading from out-of-bounds and *another* case of UB.

Comment: @Stuart2041 The output you get doesn't matter, because you don't write the contents of `buffer2` to the file.

Comment: I did not how `@Karthik Nayak` said but now it adds a 3 only on a file, it's fine right?

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 0):

First of all `snprintf` returns an integer that is the number of chars that would have been written if the string were not truncated (as you can read on the [snprintf manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf))

you cannot then use it in the `write` command. You can then use:

```
 if ( snprintf(buffer2, 10,"%d",listBoard[2]) >= 10 ) {
    /* handle truncation error*/
 }
 if(write(file_write,buffer2,18)!=18){
     err_sys("write_error");
```

Anyway since buffer2 is maximum 10 characters why do you expect to write 18 bytes?

Other possible error: buffer2 should be at least of 10 + 1 byte for null termination.

Comment: what size should be buffer2?, anyways I'm not getting how to print the `space` and  `\n`?

Comment: Your code has several issues, we focused on your question. For printing all the all the data you should then expect to have a loop to iterate over the array element. Try first to print it to stdout without focusing on the buffer size, then you do it on a file and than you introduce snprintf.

Answer (score 0):

You never specify that you must use raw file descriptors, so let's port your code up one level to C's standard library's `FILE` abstraction. It's easier to work with.

```
void printToFile(const int listBoard[]) {
  FILE * const out = fopen("board.txt", "wt");
  if (out == NULL) {
    err_sys("error output file");
  }
  for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
      fprintf(out, "%d ", listBoard[3 * j + i]);
    fprintf(out, "\n");
  }
  fclose(out);
}
```

Note that this uses loops to iterate over the elements of the board array, this seemed to be missing from your original code and part of the problem you had with it.

This prints:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

There's a trailing space on each line due to me being lazy, but hopefully that's fine. Also I omitted some inner error checking.

Comment: OP is using open not fopen, maybe it's not a good idea change the way to do it.

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS Well yes, I did notice that and I think it's a bad idea for what seems like a beginner. I mention this at the very start of my answer.